# Qt multiple form entries save to and load from file

Tags: c++, forms, qt

In my application, I have multiple forms that show up sequentially. Also, the number and type of fields in current form depend on the fields entered in the previous form.

```
Eg. In a Form, Number of Feeders : 10 (user entered)  
Now in next form, sub-fields for 10 feeders shall be shown.
```

I am generating the fields (`QLineEdits`, `QComboBoxes` etc) on the heap and calling the next form by `dialogNoX->exec()` function. Hence the previous dialog windows remain open.

Now since the number of entries is very large, I want to give the user an option of saving the present partially entered fields/forms and re-loading it for future reference.

What can be a convenient way to do so? I am at present thinking of `QtXML` but the thing is that I don't have a nice structure of nested tagged elements. For my case, each field is almost independent of the other.

Any other options that I have? As I said, the number of entries and their possible values is large.

Comment: It depends. If your partial form does not need to be share with other applications or for human reading, you can use the simple Qt serialization system

Comment: @vahancho Yes QSettings is an option but then the user can save at most one configuration, whereas in my case the user may have multiple configurations of input for future reference.

Comment: @jbh Yes I do not need the saved file to be read by any other human or application. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, you can have multiple `QSettings` instances that work with multiple settings files (ini format). I am not aware of any limitation in the number of configurations. `QSettings` also allows some sort of hierarchy too.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Have a look at [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html) to see if you can write your objects in a simple binary file and recover them later in the same structure

Comment: I would consider using QSettings with groups to create a hierarchy. If there is not a hierarchy already in your data you could generate a QUuid and use that as the root group for a set of settings.